# Declaring array length, JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I have to make two new arrays from this existing one, one will have positive values, and one negative, not including 0. If this logic is right, I only have one problem, declaring the length of these two, new arrays. I'm a beginner in programming.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
    int[] array1 = new int [];
    int[] array2 = new int [];
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i]>0) {
        if(array[i]==0)
            continue;
        int[] array1 = new int[];

        array1[i]=array[i];
    } else if(array[i]<0) {
        if(array[i]==0)
            continue;

        array2[i]=array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking `if(array[i]==0)` inside the `if(array[i]>0)` block, makes no sense.

Comment: Your code doesnt compile, you must declare the size of the array first. You should iterate on `array` and count how many positives and negatives elements are. Then, instantiate `array1` and `array2` with the given size

Comment: ok, I ll try that out, ty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your algorithm to do it in two passes, like this:

- Go through the array once, and count how many items will end up in each sub-array
- Instantiate the arrays with the counts obtained during the first step
- Go through the array again, and populate the results.

When you implement this, node that this code uses incorrect index for `array1` and `array2`:

```
array1[i] = array[i];
array2[i] = array[i];
```

You need two separate indexes for each side:

```
array1[positiveIndex++] = array[i];
array2[negativeIndex++] = array[i];
```

Alternatively, you could use a collection that can grow as you add items to it (e.g. `ArrayList<Integer>`) if your exercise allows for it. This approach is a lot simpler, because it requires only a single pass.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Java 8 then you could just do

```
int[] array = new int[]{12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};

int[] positives = Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> x > 0).toArray();
int[] negatives = Arrays.stream(array).filter(x -> x < 0).toArray();
```

Comment: I have to use loops because that's what we are learning now, this is my assignment, to pratctice arrays and loops. :/

Comment: Then you have to do as dasblinkenlight explained